# AvalonEdit XAML for COBOL

Tags: cobol, avalonedit

Does anyone know if an AvalonEdit XAML syntax for COBOL exists?

I will resort to making one if it doesn't exist yet, but it could be wrong since I don't know the language very well.

Comment: Notepad ++ has syntax highlighting for COBOL, you may be able to steal the parts you need from their langs.model file to create the XAML quicker (rather than just from scratch).

Comment: @SaggingRufus That's exactly what I did. Thanks!

Comment: @LiamAllan to get a (set of) quite complete word list for different COBOL dialects you may want to check the "*.words" files from https://sourceforge.net/p/open-cobol/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/config/ - your Editor syntax may have another option to provide multiples sets (if not it is still nice to include other than your default as comments).

It would be nice to leave your work at https://github.com/icsharpcode/AvalonEdit/pulls allowing people to inspect (or even directly use) it.

Comment: Thanks for .words suggestion, I will take a look. A pull request, what a great idea. I will be submitting more than just COBOL as I also have created RPG too - which I also created for Notepad++.